# Fallout 4 patch - Reunions mission

Tags: fallout-4

I'm on PS4 and still waiting for the patch release, but the announcement says:

- Fixed issue where equipped weapons become locked after completing Reunions

Reunions is the first main mission that I have finished.  I don't understand what they mean with `equipped weapons become locked`. Is it my weapons or the weapons of companions being locked?  I don't think I have experienced that on PS4.

Comment: Your weapon becomes locked and is unavailable to use.

Comment: Does the bug always happen when you finish the `reunions` mission?  Because I still can perfectly shoot around.

Comment: No the issue doesn't always happen, which is probably why you didn't see it